# AngularJS to render a template inside a compile inside a loop inside a partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a partial, which has a directive which renders a bunch of things in a loop, using compiled HMTL-as-a-string inside the directive. This HTML-as-a-string itself contains an `ng-include`, which doesn't render out.

Please see my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opyate/kf3vZ/)

Basically, this doesn't include `template2.html`:

```
element.html('<span>The name is ' + scope.content.name + '!</span><div ng-include src="template2.html"></div><br>');
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/dXsUV/)

just needed to write as

```
src=" \'template2.html\'"


var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html('<span>The name is ' + scope.content.name + '!</span><div ng-include src=" \'template2.html\'"></div><br>');
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
};
```

more info in [DOCS](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)

Comment: Just in case it's non-obvious from the above: the change was to quote the ng-include src as it's a constant not something to lookup in the scope. The relevant [line in the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c0ad2efb24e4fffff6cb503ca821fe7e0bd4618b/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L35)

Answer (score 3):

Vinod's answer above (replace `src="template2.html"` with `src="\'template2.html\'"`) is correct, though I would recommend using an actual template instead of manually compiling the template yourself inside the link function.  In your example, you aren't actually receiving the benefit of the two way binding.  You are just taking the html output of the compile function, and it will never update if the underlying data changes.  Here is your example modified to show the bindings (and Vinod's template fix):

http://jsfiddle.net/kf3vZ/5/

Notice how if you change the value of any of the checkboxes, the value in the directives do not change.

Now here is a version using the `template` argument to the directive:

http://jsfiddle.net/kf3vZ/7/

Now if you change the text fields, the directive values will change also.

Another note, since you are already using the `script` tags for your templates, you could replace `template` in your directive with `templateUrl` and provide the `id` of the script template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sure I'll run into this scenario soon enough now that I've overcome the first hurdle, so I'll just refer back here for advice.